# Click "submit", send data, but keep the page from redirecting to the new URL

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome-extension, reload

**What my script does:**

- I open https://mylink.com/#script

  - The script in my chrome extension checks for the #script in the URL and calls a function
  - The function clicks some checkboxes and then a "submit" button
  - After 3 seconds the script refreshes the website **with the hashtag** to create an infinite loop

**Problem:**

- The data from the checkboxes/submit need to go through to the server - that's why I have to wait some time before refreshing. The 3 seconds seem to be enough for that.
- Sometimes the website takes 15 seconds until it redirects me to the new site after submitting, but sometimes it's lightning fast and opens the new website before the 3 seconds before the reload have passed - since the opened website doesn't have the `#script`, my loop stops working.

**What I need help with:**

- How long does it take to send the information from the form so they get through to the server? I know that I don't have to wait for the server's answer and the redirection to the new page, but I think I can't refresh instantly.
- Is there a way to detect at which point the new site will be opened so the script could call a function before that happens and redirect to the URL with the hashtag? Or even better: Detect the moment when the information is completely sent from the client side and then instantly refresh.
- **I would like to keep the time the whole loop needs as short as possible!**

**Code for understanding:**

*The submit form on the website:*

```
<form action="/withdraw-request" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="YEZknGzr-HW1ThkFrf9bO1M_IuQRJSVk-W6M">

<div id="items">...contains checkboxes...</div>

<input class="button right blue" type="submit" value="Withdraw selected items">

</form>
```

*My content.js (in the chrome extension):*

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);


    if(window.location.hash=="#script") {

    var tradestatus = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    console.log("Offer-status: " + tradestatus[8].innerHTML);


    var oneKeyOnly = true;


    function checkItem() {
    var itemsArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Melons", ];
    var matchingItems = [];
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for(var y = 0; y < x.length; y++){
        if(itemsArray.indexOf(x[y].getAttribute("data-name")) >= 0){
            var id = x[y].getElementsByClassName("item-checkbox")[0].getAttribute("id");
            matchingItems.push(id);
        }
    }
    return matchingItems;
}


function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function clickButton(val)
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
       if(buttons[i].type == 'submit' && buttons[i].value == val) 
       {
           buttons[i].click();
           console.log("Trying to withdraw!");
           break;
       }
    }
}

var result = checkItem();
var lengthOfArray = result.length - 1;

if (oneKeyOnly == true) {
var rand = randomIntFromInterval(0,lengthOfArray);
document.getElementById(result[rand]).checked = true
console.log("Found: " + result[rand]);
}
else {

for(index=0, len = result.length; index < len; ++index) {
    document.getElementById(result[index]).checked = true
    keynr = index + 1;
    console.log("Found " + result.length + " fruits - Selected Nr. " + keynr + "!");
}

}
clickButton("Withdraw selected items");

unloadready = true;


setTimeout((function(){ location.reload(true) }), 3000);




}

    }
    }, 10);
});
```

*Withdraw.js:*
Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9q72Ti2b
It gets called from somewhere. I can see it in the "network" tab next to the chrome console.

---

## Edit_1:

I tried to use google for a while now and found an ajax documentation and a piece of code that I tried to modify so it would work for me. There is still some really basic stuff that I don't understand.

**The code:**

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: withdraw-request,
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            items,
            _csrf
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert('Success!');
            location.reload(true);
        }               
    });
});
```

Here is the form again from that website with one of the checkboxes added.

```
<form action="/withdraw-request" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="YEZknGzr-HW1ThkFrf9bO1M_IuQRJSVk-W6M">

<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="34155017" class="item-checkbox" id="item-34155017" data-price="562500">

<input class="button right blue" type="submit" value="Withdraw selected items">

</form>
```

So if I understand it right, then the website is using POST to send "_csrf" and "items" to "withdraw-request" (added the names to "data" in the code).

- Why is there nothing like ".php" on "withdraw-request"?
- How can I call this code if the form doesn't have a name for its own?
- How can I add something like "onClick" or "onSubmit" to a website that is not my own and where I can't change the actual code? *Solved that one myself!*

  document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[1].setAttribute("onsubmit", "specialFunction()");

---

## Edit_2:

Kind of made it work:

I added this to my 'content.js' to add a name to the form and an ajax function:

```
var formAdd = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');
formAdd[1].setAttribute("id", "submitthisform");


    var $form = $("#submitthisform");

// register handler for submit first
$form.submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    })
    .done(function (data) {   

    })
    .fail(function (r, s, e) {

    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I can call this by `$form.submit();`. It seems to work, but it still redirects to the new page. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: dont use a form and submit. Just use ajax to post the data and that wont trigger a refresh

Comment: I am not the owner of the website. I am just performing automated actions there from the client side. Or do you mean I could bypass clicking the button? I am new to coding, could I have a hint?

Comment: Add `onclick` handler to your button or better `onsubmit` to your form. After all actions you want to do `return false;` to avoid form submit.

Comment: Added something to my original post!